# How to configure gcc to use -no-pie by default?

Tags: gcc, configuration, ld, gnu-assembler, position-independent-code

I want to compile the following program on Linux:

```
    .global _start
    .text
_start:
    mov $1,   %rax
    mov $1,   %rdi
    mov $msg, %rsi
    mov $13,  %rdx
    syscall
    mov $60,  %rax
    xor %rdi, %rdi
    syscall
msg:
    .ascii "Hello World!\n"
```

However, it gives me the following linker error:

```
$ gcc -nostdlib hello.s
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccMNQrOF.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.text' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I figured that the reason it doesn't work is because gcc is using `-pie` to generate a shared object by default. Thus, using `-no-pie` fixes it:

```
$ gcc -no-pie -nostdlib hello.s
$ ./a.out
Hello World!
```

How do I configure gcc to use `-no-pie` by default? I'm using Arch Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess just don't configure gcc with `--enable-default-pie`.

See this blog post: http://nanxiao.me/en/gccs-enable-enable-default-pie-option-make-you-stuck-at-relocation-r_x86_64_32s-against-error/, and Arch patch that enabled pie by default: https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/commit/trunk?h=packages/gcc&id=5936710c764016ce306f9cb975056e5b7605a65b.

Comment: So the solution is to always use `-no-pie`? It seems that if I configure gcc without `--enable-default-pie` it might break something.

Comment: gcc configured with `--enable-default-pie` is a security hardening strategy as it builds position independent binaries by default. Building no pie binaries by default could be less secure, but it should not break anything.

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose you have to re-compile gcc to disable default PIE. Or you will need `-no-pie` each time you want to compile position dependent assembly code.

However, just for the example you provided, a better way is to use relative addressing like `label_name(%rip)`.

Relative addressing allows PIE to function properly.

I modified yours into this: (see the `leaq` line)

```
.global _start
.text
_start:
    movq $1,        %rax
    movq $1,        %rdi
    leaq msg(%rip), %rsi
    movq $13,       %rdx
    syscall
    movq $60,       %rax
    xorq %rdi,      %rdi
    syscall
.section .rodata
msg:
    .ascii "Hello World!\n"
```

(I added `.section .rodata` just because usually this should be put into rodata section. Your version works fine, but output of `objdump -d` contains meaningless instructions from `msg` label.)